# Failing to parse response json into an object with Angular2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-http

I am trying to follow these directions: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html and get the list of objects from the server in form of an object (not json).

I have a model class (simplified for now):

```
export class Goal {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

And I am trying to get list of these from the server through a service class as follows:

```
export class GoalsService {

  constructor(public authHttp:AuthHttp) {
  }

  getGoals() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.authHttp.get('<%= BACKEND_BASE_URL %>' + '/rrm/api/v1/goals', options)
      .map(res => {
          <Goal[]> res.json()
        }
      )
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
...
```

And the client using the service class is:

```
loadGoals() {
    this.goalsService.getGoals().subscribe(
      goals => this.goals = goals
    );
  }
```

The request goes through properly and I am getting back:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"target"}]
```

However, in the client, inside `subscribe`, `goals` variable is always 'undefined'.

I tried debugging it, this is what I get:
[image]

Which says to me that json received and parsed properly, but casting it into a target object is not working (unless I am not fully getting the mechanism).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Note: the `authHttp` service that I use is this guy: https://auth0.com/blog/2015/11/10/introducing-angular2-jwt-a-library-for-angular2-authentication/. And it works in all other places as expected. So I doubt that it is a peoblem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `map` arrow function, you should `return` mapped result.

```
return this.authHttp.get('<%= BACKEND_BASE_URL %>' + '/rrm/api/v1/goals', options)
  .map(res => {
      return <Goal[]> res.json(); //return mapped object from here
    }
)
```

**OR**

```
return this.authHttp.get('<%= BACKEND_BASE_URL %>' + '/rrm/api/v1/goals', options)
  .map(res => <Goal[]> res.json()) //or simply do map object directly
```

Comment: Thank you! Works! I'll accept the answer in 4 minutes :)

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky Glad to help you. Thanks :-)